# Convert a space delimited string to list

Tags: python, string

i have a string like this :

```
states = "Alaska Alabama Arkansas American Samoa Arizona California Colorado"
```

and I want to split it into a list like this

```
states = {Alaska, Alabama, Arkansas, American, Samoa, ....}
```

I am new in python.

Help me, please. :-))

edit: I need to make a random choice from states and make it like the variable.

Comment: what do you mean by "make it like variable"?

Comment: Why do you want to split "American Samoa" into two elements?

Comment: Love that this was answered identically by 5 people within 1 minute of each other.

Comment: Off-topic, but for search's sake : [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894283/812102).

Answer (score 98):

`states.split()` will return

```
['Alaska',
 'Alabama',
 'Arkansas',
 'American',
 'Samoa',
 'Arizona',
 'California',
 'Colorado']
```

If you need one random from them, then you have to use the `random` module:

```
import random

states = "... ..."

random_state = random.choice(states.split())
```

Comment: My favorite state is the state of American, which is right next to Samoa

Answer (score 62):

try

```
states.split()
```

it returns the list

```
['Alaska',
 'Alabama',
 'Arkansas',
 'American',
 'Samoa',
 'Arizona',
 'California',
 'Colorado']
```

and this returns the random element of the list

```
import random
random.choice(states.split())
```

split statement parses the string and returns the list, by default it's divided into the list by spaces, if you specify the string it's divided by this string, so for example

```
states.split('Ari')
```

returns

```
['Alaska Alabama Arkansas American Samoa ', 'zona California Colorado']
```

Btw, list is in python interpretated with [] brackets instead of {} brackets, {} brackets are used for dictionaries, you can read more on this [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)

I see you are probably new to python, so I'd give you some advice how to use python's great documentation

Almost everything you need can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)
You can use also python included documentation, open python console and write help()
If you don't know what to do with some object, I'd install ipython, write statement and press Tab, great tool which helps you with interacting with the language

I just wrote this here to show that python is great tool also because it's great documentation and it's really powerful to know this

Comment: {} brackets are also used for set literals.

Answer (score 31):

```
states = "Alaska Alabama Arkansas American Samoa Arizona California Colorado"
states_list = states.split (' ')
```

Answer (score 10):

```
states_list = states.split(' ')
```

In regards to your edit:

```
from random import choice
random_state = choice(states_list)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use string's `split()` method.

```
states.split()
```

Comment: Oh, that was easy. Thank you very much :-)