# How can I convert a list into string format in python list?

Tags: python, string, list

I was wondering how I could change a list written as a string, such as ‘[1,[2,[]],[3,[]]]’ into an actual python list like [1,[2,[]],[3,[]]]. Is there any algorithm for this?

Comment: What about `json.loads` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python)

Comment: `eval("[1,[2,[]],[3,[]]]")`

Comment: @WoodyPride `eval` is dangerous because it will execute code in the input.

Answer (score -1):

This topic have a lot of examples of solutions for your problem :)

[Python - convert string to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266529/python-convert-string-to-list)

Regards,

Answer (score -2):

Assign your value to a variable then call the variable.split() it defaults to comma delimited which in your instance would result in list['[1,[2,[]],[3,[]]]']

another example of this could be this:

```
a = "test, 1, testing2, alpha, beta, Zulu, 23"
a.split()
Result: ['test,', '1,', 'testing2,', 'alpha,', 'beta,', 'Zulu,', '23']
```

Comment: sorry I forgot that split is default space delimited if you do a.split(",")  you end up with a comma delimited python list