# How do I convert a string to a list without modifying any data in it in python?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I convert from a string to a list? I want my string to be exactly the same, but as a list.
Is that possible in python? If so, how do I do so?

Comment: can provide an example with sample data?

Comment: `list('test')` or `list(my_str_var)` should be enough I think ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
string_ex = "define here your string"

string_ex.split()
```

and

```
string_ex = "your string"
list(string_ex)
```

I hope it will help you

Also see this one it's help you :
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266559/5747242

Comment: Is it possible to do it with integers from a string?

Comment: can you define in details with example? @DavidTECDavidGames999

Comment: A list that has been written as a string, example: [[192, 0], [168, 1]] that then is made back into a string. the problem that I found with what you linked me was that the integers were written as strings. Since how I want it, it saves the entire list into a file as a string.
So, what I want,
A list that can be converted into a string and back that can be saved in a file through python

Comment: I am not  clearly understand  can you define what your input and what you want output @DavidTECDavidGames999

Comment: What I want is a file that is made with python to contain a list that can be used to define variables that can also be changed. Really just a list in a file that can be edited from a python script.

Comment: that is not relevant to your question can you please ask new question or edit this one Thank you!! @DavidTECDavidGames999